# Objective-C - detect iBeacon Connections (iPad advertising)

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon

I have an `iPad` working as an `iBeacon Advertiser` for a given region. I wonder if there is a way to detect (in my `iPad`) if any device enters in this region and if it's possible, what kind of information can I have from this device? I have read the documentation (`CoreLocation` and `CoreBluetooth`) and I could find anything.

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no. Beacon advertisement is a one-way broadcast. The receiving device does not send anything back (at least not automatically.)

The longer answer is that you could build a solution to this. You would need to write code for the receiving app that would detect entering the beacon region and respond by sending a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) transmission of its own.

You could have your receiving device advertise it's own beacon signal when it detects your iPad, or you could set up your receiving device start "advertising" as a BLE "Peripheral" (These are the BLE terms for this stuff.)

BLE is set up for two-way communications, but iBeacons are not. iBeacons are a very simple, limited API built on top of BLE.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apple's sample to see how iBeacons work. You can do what you want but there are limitations.

GO here:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013

Checkout the sample called AirLocate.

This should be sufficient to show you what can be done.

You can have the app detect when it goes into a region in the background, present an alert to the user and then also run some code whilst the app is still in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple project for two-way communication over Bluetooth LE, you might want to check out this project: [SimpleShare: Easy Proximity-based Bluetooth LE Sharing for iOS](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)

The project is more focused on exchanging information between two devices that are within bluetooth range, and less on focusing on the particulars of the distance between two devices, but you might be able to make some changes on your own or incorporate some other projects that look at the RSSI values to add in some of the distance-based functionality that iBeacons use to the project. [This project](http://github.com/Instrument/Vicinity/) is an all-CoreBluetooth implementation of distance-based features similar to iBeacon, but not relying on the CoreLocation framework, which you might be able to use with [SimpleShare](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share) to get both the distance features and the information-exchanging features working in your app.